# $f(x)$ is a periodic function. What is its period?

Tags: functions

Suppose that 
$f(x)$ is a periodic function. If we have:
$$\forall x :f(x+346)=\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}$$ 
What is its minimum period?

Comment: You mean "what is its maximal possible fundamental period?"

Comment: @whacka: You could also ask "what are all the possible fundamental periods?" — which, at least if $f$ is to be real-valued, is not an equivalent question, as $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ has no real fixed points.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $f(x+k\cdot 346)$ for the first few values of $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a = 346$.

$$f(x +2a) = f\left( (x + a) + a \right) = \frac{1 + f(x+a)}{1 - f(x+a)} = \frac{1 + \frac{1 + f(x)}{1 - f(x)}}{1 - \frac{1 + f(x)}{1 - f(x)}} = \ldots = -\frac1{f(x)}$$

Now, $f(x + 4a) = ?$

Comment: $f(x+4(346)) =f(x)$  so period is $t=4(346)$ thank both of you

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
f(x+k.346)&=f(x+(k-1).346+346)\\
&=\frac{1+f(x+(k-1).346)}{1-f(x+(k-1).346)}\\
&=\frac{1+\frac{1+f(x+(k-2).346)}{1-f(x+(k-2).346)}}{1-\frac{1+f(x+(k-2).346)}{1-f(x+(k-2).346)}}\\
&=\frac{-1}{f(x+(k-2).346)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{\frac{1+f(x+(k-3).346)}{1-f(x+(k-3).346)}}\\
&=\frac{f(x+(k-3).346)-1}{f(x+(k-3).346)+1}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+f(x+(k-4).346)}{1-f(x+(k-4).346)}-1}{\frac{1+f(x+(k-4).346)}{1-f(x+(k-4).346)}+1}\\
&=\frac{2f(x+(k-4).346)}{2}\\
&=f(x+(k-4).346)  
\end{align}$$
so we have: $$f(x+k.346)=f(x+(k-4).346)$$
if we take $k=4$ we will have: $$f(x+4\times 346)=f(x)$$
so the period is $4\times 346$